# Node js return can not set after headers they are sent

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm having a problem with node.js he return-an error on the console saying:

```
Error: Can not set after headers They are sent.
```

Right here the part of my code that is returning the error:

```
app.post ('/ register', function (req, res) {
    var = usuarioCadastro req.body.usuario;
    var = emailCadastro req.body.email;
    var = telefoneCadastro req.body.telefone;
    var = senhaCadastro req.body.senha;

    console.log ("User:" + usuarioCadastro);
    console.log ("Email:" + emailCadastro);
    console.log ("Telephone" + telefoneCadastro);
    console.log ("Password" + senhaCadastro);

      pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?',[emailCadastro], function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (var i in rows){ var emailBanco = rows[i].email; }
            if(emailCadastro === emailBanco){
                console.log("Email já foi cadastrado");
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send({ code: '303', mensagem:'This email already signup' });

            }else{
                var sql = {usuario:usuarioCadastro,email:emailCadastro,senha:senhaCadastro};
                pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',[sql], function(err, rows, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log("Novo usuario cadastrado");
                    res.send({ code: '200', mensagem:'Sucess, welcome to trimtrim' });

                });/*Second Query*/

            }/* Else */
```

});/* First Query*/

I've been researching and from what I saw, the expression can only send once. I need to send more times. What do I do?

Comment: no you don't. You can literally only send them once, that's how HTTP works. So, instead, you can aggregate all the headers you need to send, and then all the way at the end, call `res.headers` with the headers you need, followed by the normal data response.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send headers once.  Aggregate your messages and send them all after your loop.

```
        connection.release ();
        var msg = '';
        for (var i in rows) {
            if (emailCadastro === rows [i] .email) {
            console.log ("Email database:" + rows [i] .email);

            if (msg.length>0) msg += '<br/>';
            msg += 'E-mail already registered: ' + rows[i].email;

            errodeForm ++;

            }

        } // For

        if (msg.length>0) res.json ({code: 303 Message: msg});
```

Comment: if you can take a look at my code , I need to return two consecutive headers not to be necessary because it is a registration check

Comment: The only place where I see that you would send more than 1 header is during your for loop.  As stated previously, you can only send headers once, and since you are only sending a status header `code: 303`, not sure what other headers you would need to send.  There is no need to send the same status multiple times.  If there are other headers you are sending, please point them out, or post that code.